# Linking to Prefs in React Native iOS app

Tags: react-native

I would like to send a user to the preferences/settings when a button is clicked. However, when I try the following, nothing happens:

LinkingIOS.openURL('prefs:root=General')

I verified that the onPress is working as when I do the following, I get redirected to Google

LinkingIOS.openURL('http://google.com')

Answer (score 5):

I just spent way too much time trying to figure this out and finally found out that this url scheme has been redacted in the late versions of ios...

:(

**However** you can redirect to your own apps settings with 'app-settings:'

Comment: saved me quite some time - thx! now only need to figure out how to do this with android..